# How is to program on Mac OS from windows (on virtual machine)

Tags: objective-c, macos

I must do simple projects on iOS.

Which is the best: to run OS X  on virtual machine, or to create bootable OS X? Ram 4 GB.
I want to use emulator.

Answer (score 3):

There is no legal way to run OS X anywhere other than on a Mac, even an emulator or VM. It's probably best to pick up a used mac for this.

Comment: I know, but I must do simply laboratories in university..

Comment: Yes, you should buy a used Mac as an investment in your education the same way you buy books and art supplies (if that's your thing). Apple also offers some pretty steep discounts for students on new equipment as well. Perhaps at the end of your term you can re-sell the mac if you no longer want it.

Comment: Also, there will likely be strange errors and performance inconsistencies if you run a hacked OS X in a VM that won't be present on the correct hardware.